# Как получить физический адрес?

Tags: c++, память

```
int p;
std::cout<<"virtual address: "<<&p<<std::endl;
```

> Output:
>
> virtual address: 0x7ffed4888ea4

Comment: И? О чем вопрос? Что такое "физический адрес"?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/converting-virtual-addresses-to-physical-addresses

Comment: В языке С++ нет такого понятия как физический адрес.

Comment: Зависит от ОС. В линукс информация в `/prоc/self/pagemap` (читать [man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html))

Comment: @Slava в языке нет, но у процессора есть, который прямо на адресных выводах идет к памяти. И если вы работаете в незащищенном режиме, в DOS-е  например, то адреса в программе будут соответствовать физическим

Comment: @PavelGridin я понимаю, но если ТС хочет знать такие детали, ему стоит спросить "как узнать в MS Windows ..." и так далее. Вопрос же "как в С++ узнать физический адрес?" смысла не имеет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

никак, если это защищённая ОС, более того соответствующий виртуальному адресу физический может постоянно меняться или вообще отсутствовать если программа в свопе